# How can I create an alias for multiple classes in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++14

I have two classes A and B defined in a large code base. I'd like to create a type alias that means "A or B". Note that this class will never switch from being an A to being a B during runtime (and vice-versa). How can I do that?

I thought of simply creating an empty class AorB and making A and B both derive from it. However I would much prefer to not have to modify A or B.

I thought of using union, but that seems wasteful from a memory perspective, as this keeps space for the biggest class.

To try and be clearer, here's code to illustrate my question:

```
class A;
class B;


//typedef AorB = A || B //<- how can I do sthg like that ?

class C {
   AorB myAorB; // once this object is set, it cannot change its underlying type (it stays an A or a B)
};
```

Comment: A `union` of `A` and `B`? Or [`std::variant<A, B>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: Other possible solutions (to your unknown problem) could be polymorphism, where you have an abstract base class that defines the interface, and then the implementation in either `A` or `B`. Then you have a pointer to the base-class and make it point to either an `A` or `B` object instance.

Comment: What about combination of two `typedef`s and `#ifdef` macro?

Comment: How do you choose between them? Why not write just `using opaque_type = A;` and then simply changing it to ` = B;` if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note that this class will never switch from being an A to being a B during runtime (and vice-versa)

You want to use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), e.g.

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool useAOrB() { /* Some actual logic here... */ return true; }

class C {
    std::conditional_t<useAOrB(), A, B> myAorB;
};
```